# Existing connexion on Apache and mod_proxy_balancer don't fail over second JBoss node

Tags: load-balancing, jboss, mod-proxy-ajp, apache-2.2

I have a Jboss farm, load balanced by Apache HTTP + mod_proxy_balancer and mod_proxy_ajp, with the following configuration :

```bsh
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName web-gui-acceptance.myorg.com
    ServerAlias web-gui-acceptance


    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass /web-gui balancer://jbosscluster/web-gui stickysession=JSESSIONID nofailover=On
    ProxyPassReverse /web-gui http://srvlnx01.myorg.com:8080/web-gui
    ProxyPassReverse /web-gui http://srvlnx02.myorg.com:8080/web-gui

    <Proxy *>
      AuthType Kerberos
      [...]
    </Proxy>

    <Proxy balancer://jbosscluster>
        BalancerMember ajp://srvlnx01.myorg.com:8009 route=SRVLNX01_node1
        BalancerMember ajp://srvlnx01.myorg.com:8009 route=SRVLNX02_node1
        ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
    </Proxy>

</VirtualHost>
```

When the first JBoss node fail (the hosting VM is down), my existing connexions don't fail over the second node ... the fist route is keeped (in table / .shm ?) and that provide me 503 errors.

Can someone tell me what I missed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have found a workaround, that also deal with deployement / undeployement : http://www.jboss.org/mod_cluster

### Advantages

> mod_cluster boasts the following advantages over other httpd-based load balancers:
>
> **Dynamic configuration of httpd workers**
>
> Traditional httpd-based load balancers require explicit configuration of the workers available to a proxy. In mod_cluster, the bulk of the proxy's configuration resides on the application servers. The set of proxies to which an application server will communicate is determined either by a static list or using dynamic discovery via the advertise mechanism. The application server relays lifecycle events (e.g. server startup/shutdown) to the proxies allowing them to effectively auto-configure themselves. Notably, the graceful shutdown of a server will not result in a failover response by a proxy, as is the case with traditional httpd-based load balancers.
>
> **Server-side load balance factor calculation**
>
> In contrast with traditional httpd-based load balancers, mod_cluster uses load balance factors calculated and provided by the application servers, rather than computing these in the proxy. Consequently, mod_cluster offers a more robust and accurate set of load metrics than is available from the proxy. (see Load Metrics for more)
>
> **Fine grained web-app lifecycle control**
>
> Traditional httpd-based load balancers do not handle web application undeployments particularly well. From the proxy's perspective requests to an undeployed web application are indistinguishable from a request for an non-existent resource, and will result in 404 errors. In mod_cluster, each server forwards any web application context lifecycle events (e.g. web-app deploy/undeploy) to the proxy informing it to start/stop routing requests for a given context to that server.
>
> **AJP is optional**
>
> Unlike mod_jk, mod_cluster does not require AJP. httpd connections to application server nodes can use HTTP, HTTPS, or AJP.
> The original concepts are described in a wiki.

I hope that will help.